# Combining 2 lists in R into data.table (and repeating all values)

Tags: arrays, r, dataframe, data.table

I have 2 arrays in R. I want to combine them into a data.table (or data.frame) such that a row is created for each value from array 1 combined with each value in array 2.

For example, if I had:

```
Array1 <- c("A", "B", "C")
Array2 <- c(1, 2, 3)
```

I want the output data.frame to look like:

```
> DF
  Array1 Array2
1      A      1
2      A      2
3      A      3
4      B      1
5      B      2
6      B      3
7      C      1
8      C      2
9      C      3
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

`data.table` has a function for this, `CJ`, that's very similar to `expand.grid`, and produces a keyed `data.table` (which can be very advantageous in advanced `data.table` joins):

```
CJ(a = Array1, b = Array2)
#   a b
#1: A 1
#2: A 2
#3: A 3
#4: B 1
#5: B 2
#6: B 3
#7: C 1
#8: C 2
#9: C 3

key(CJ(a = Array1, b = Array2))
#[1] "a" "b"
```

Answer (score 1):

The obvious choice:

```
expand.grid(Array1,Array2)
```

If you need the variable names:

```
expand.grid(Array1=Array1,Array2=Array2)
```

Result:

```
#  Array1 Array2
#1      A      1
#2      B      1
#3      C      1
#4      A      2
#5      B      2
#6      C      2
#7      A      3
#8      B      3
#9      C      3
```

If you specifically need a `data.table` output, as @mnel suggests you can do:

```
out <- setDT(expand.grid(Array1=Array1,Array2=Array2))
```